# How do you use Windows Remote Desktop to connect to Remmina?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, remmina

I have a Chromebook with a Linux Virtual Environment that is a Debian 12 Bookworm.

I installed Remmina after looking to RDP to my Windows XP OS. I know that I can connect to my Windows OS from Linux but how do you do the reverse?

I want to remote connect from Windows to Remmina but I have no idea how to actually do it. Is it possible to do this? Is there any way to make it a server?

Answer (score 1):

Remmina is just a [Remote Desktop *client*](https://www.reddit.com/r/Remmina/comments/10y0mt9/how_to_run_connect_to_a_remote_linux_pc/) (RDP), i.e., *viewer*. It allows connection only from a user on Linux to control a RDP server on another PC. Think of Remmina as a desktop browser, as Firefox or Tor are web browsers.

To access a Linux machine remotely, whether from Windows or Linux, you need a RDP *server*, such as [GNOME Remote Desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en).

[GNOME RDP can be installed](https://devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa/installing-gnome-remote-desktop-on-ubuntu20-04.html) from Terminal with the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install gnome-remote-desktop
```

Or you could [download the .deb package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnome-remote-desktop) to install offline.